# Is battery life affected with dual boot?

Tags: laptop, battery

I have dual booted my laptop with Windows 10 and Linux. Does this affect battery life?

(My laptop has a i5 processor with 2.2 GHZ RAM and 500 GB HD.)

Comment: Well, there may be a few options that affect battery life, such as screen brightness and how much reading and writing is being done to the disk. They differ from Windows to Linux, but in general , dual or tripple boot doesn't automatically mean different battery life.

Answer (score 3):

Your battery itself doesn't care if you have installed 1,2,3 or X operating systems on your disks.

You might realize that some operating system is taking/using more or less power when active then another operating system (again when active) which is expected behaviour as each operating system is different

Battery consumption is related on the one side how software is using hardware (using drivers) and on the other side what the user is doing with the software.

Example: gaming 3D games might consume more power then modifying a html document.

Answer (score 0):

That has been my experience with my Dell 3190 2-in-1 laptop with Windows 11 Pro and Linux Ubuntu Mate installed on a 128 GB SSD. The partitioning is 50 GB for Windows and the remaining for Linux. The battery usually lasts 10 hours with Windows, but with Linux I get 8 hours and I do the same processes on both OSes of emails, web browsing, and streaming music. I am not a gamer.

Comment: But that is not because of the dual-boot, but because of Windows having better power drivers.